# Application Crashes on [scrollView removeFromSuperview];

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview, cocos2d-iphone

Hell All,

I am new to iPhone and struggling with following problem.
When i remove scroll view with following statement my appli crashes.

```
[scrollView removeFromSuperview];
```

I am adding uiscrollview with following line.

```
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

Hereis the log.

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34a80466 objc_msgSend + 18
1   UIKit                           0x341aaaa8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 152
2   UIKit                           0x341aaace -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 190
3   UIKit                           0x341aaace -[UIView(Hierarchy) _makeSubtreePerformSelector:withObject:withObject:copySublayers:] + 190
4   UIKit                           0x341c05a0 -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 208
5   UIKit                           0x34249a76 -[UIScrollView removeFromSuperview] + 42
6   KabushikiShimbun                0x000387b6 -[PDFPageScrollViewController ReGenerateScrollViewAsperNewData] (PDFPageScrollViewController.m:1451)
7   KabushikiShimbun                0x00038aac -[PDFPageScrollViewController CheckPageUpdationWithDate:] (PDFPageScrollViewController.m:1441)
8   KabushikiShimbun                0x0003c472 -[PDFPageScrollViewController requestFinished:] (PDFPageScrollViewController.m:792)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x35818bb8 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] + 16
10  KabushikiShimbun                0x0000e9ba -[ASIHTTPRequest reportFinished] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:1945)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x35818bb8 -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] + 16
12  Foundation                      0x3118178e __NSThreadPerformPerform + 262
13  CoreFoundation                  0x358307d6 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 6
14  CoreFoundation                  0x358025b0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 376
15  CoreFoundation                  0x35801e54 __CFRunLoopRun + 224
16  CoreFoundation                  0x35801c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
17  CoreFoundation                  0x35801b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
18  GraphicsServices                0x320c84a4 GSEventRunModal + 108
19  GraphicsServices                0x320c8550 GSEventRun + 56
20  UIKit                           0x341dc322 -[UIApplication _run] + 406
21  UIKit                           0x341d9e8c UIApplicationMain + 664
22  KabushikiShimbun                0x00002da6 main (main.m:14)
23  KabushikiShimbun                0x00002d70 start + 32
```

Any Idea ? 
Thank you.

Comment: Can you post some code? Its probably a invalid object.

Comment: have you checked with debugger ?like where it crashing with line ?/

Comment: are you using scrollview firstresponder ?

Comment: when does [scrollView removeFromSuperview]; get called?

Comment: try setting up an NSLog statement right before `[scrollView removeFromSuperview]` to see how many times it is called.  i've had the same type of issue using gesture recognizers where they get called multiple times (for reasons i still can't figure out besides a possible ios bug).  the second time they are called, it removes nothing from the superview and crashes the app

Comment: I would want to double check that the scrollview hasn't be deallocated already, so make sure whatever "self.view" is hasn't been deallocated yet. If you can share more code, it would help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews)

{
    if([view isMemberOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
    {
        [scrollview removeFromSuperView];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check whether it has a superview before removing from superview;

```
if([scrollView superview]!=nil){
    [scrollView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It's tested.

```
NSArray *subviews = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:self.view.subviews];
for(UIScrollView *subview in subviews) {
    [subview removeFromSuperView];
}
[subviews release];
```

but be carefull it removes all `ScrollViews` present in your `self.view`